# Output of abi.encodeCall - is it one or more bytes32?

Tags: encode

I am looking at a contract that uses abi.encodeCall. I'm wondering whether the result of abi.encodeCall(//CALL INFO//) will always result in a bytes32.

The larger reason I am asking is that this abi.encodeCall(//CALL INFO//) is included together with v, r, s and the whole thing is subject to abi.encode (see below). I know you can only use abi.encode on bytes32. I know that v, r, s are bytes32, but I don't know what results from abi.encodeCall.

```
abi.encode(v, r, s, abi.encodeCall(//CALL INFO//))
```

Comment: The triplet `(v, r, s)` indicates you're working with ECDSA signatures. Note that in that case `v` is of type `uint8` and not `bytes32`.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `abi.encodeCall()` is `bytes`. See the docs [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.23/cheatsheet.html#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions).

The data to call a function is composed of the `bytes4` function selector concatenated with the abi-encoded arguments. As the number and types of the arguments differ between functions, the data returned by `abi.encodeCall()` must be dynamic.

Also, note that `abi.encode()` can take any type of input argument, not just `bytes32`.